# Swift 3 - Local Notification's didReceiveRemoteNotification function not fired

Tags: swift, notifications, swift3, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I have managed to schedule a notification and show it to the user when the app is running/not running in the foreground. Now I need to display a `ViewController` upon the tap of this notification.

I understand that `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is the function that is called when the user taps on a notification. In my case, **This function is never fired.**

**AppDelegate:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }

        return true
}

//didReceiveRemoteNotification goes here
```

**The didReceiveRemoteNotification function:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active)
        {
            print("Active")
            // App is foreground and notification is recieved,
            // Show a alert.
        }
        else if( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background)
        {
            print("Background")
            // App is in background and notification is received,
            // You can fetch required data here don't do anything with UI.
        }
        else if( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive)
        {
            print("Inactive")
            // App came in foreground by used clicking on notification,
            // Use userinfo for redirecting to specific view controller.
        }
}
```

This is the entire Notification related code in my `AppDelegate`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`UserNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/) framework you need to work with [`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate), so implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` with `AppDelegate` and set the delegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }

    return true
}
```

Now you need to implements [`userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter) and [`userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) methods to get notification.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    //Handle notification
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // pull out the buried userInfo dictionary
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let customData = userInfo["customData"] as? String {
        print("Custom data received: \(customData)")

        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            // the user swiped to unlock
            print("Default identifier")

        case "show":
            // the user tapped our "show more info…" button
            print("Show more information…")
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // you must call the completion handler when you're done
    completionHandler()
}
```

You can also check this **AppCoda** tutorial [`Introduction to User Notifications Framework in iOS 10`](http://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/) for more details.

Comment: Haha Nirav thanks for posting answers on all the iOS question I've been asking the past few days. Very new to it so I'm full of questions ;) And yes your answer works BUT it gets fired when the notification is received. **What function do I need to implement to capture the 'tap' event?**

Comment: @RickGrimesLikesWalkerSoup For that implement this method https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`.

Comment: Beautiful. It works. May I ask one last sub-question if it's not too much trouble. How can I identify which notification was tapped on? As in, identify the notification by their identifier and then open different view controllers?

Comment: @RickGrimesLikesWalkerSoup you can get that using `response.actionIdentifier`.

Comment: Can you link me to an example please?

Comment: Nice. Thanks bro!